# Perl accessing package constant from different package

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I'm learning OOP in Perl right now.

Is there a way without any additional libraries (it is forbidden to use any additional lib) to access variable from one package in another one?

```
package Class;

my $CONSTANT = 'foo'; # this doesn't work, neither our $CONSTANT ..

# ...
# class methodes
# ...

package main;

print Class::$CONSTANT ."\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Your constant declaration is wrong

Constants do not have a `$` before their name because they are not variables -- a variable (as implied by the name) contains a value which can vary.

Try this (it uses the `constant` module but that's included in the default installation:

```
use constant CONSTANT => "Foo";
```

### Accessing class constants

You can then access them as:

```
Class::CONSTANT # I suggest NOT using this as 'Class::Constant' is a module name, rename your class to something useful
```

Or, if you have `$obj` as an instance of `Class`:

```
$obj->CONSTANT;
```

### Sample code showing both access methods

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package MyClass;
use constant SOME_CONSTANT => 'Foo';
sub new
{
   my $type = shift;                   # The package/type name
   my $self = {};                      # Empty hash
   return bless $self, $type;
}

package main;
print MyClass::SOME_CONSTANT . "\n";   # Prints 'Foo\n'

my $obj = MyClass->new();
print $obj->SOME_CONSTANT;             # Prints 'Foo'
```

[And a demo](https://eval.in/44711).

Comment: I used "Class" just in this example. Thank you.

Comment: @Hologos That's fine, but I need to leave that there in case someone reading my answer thinks it's a good idea to call their class `Class`.

Answer (score 2):

Easy mistake to make. Put the sigil in front of the class name, e.g.

```
print ${Class::CONSTANT} . "\n";
print $Class::CONSTANT . "\n";
```

In addition constants can be defined using the `constant` package, e.g.

```
use constant MY_CONSTANT => 5;
print MY_CONSTANT();
```

Comment: You haven't even pointed out that a `$` sigil indicates a variable rather than a constant. I can't see why you're getting any upvotes...

Comment: @SweetieBelle I acknowledge your point; however in this case the OP specifically asked how to access a variable. That this variable was named `CONSTANT` doesn't change the fact it was a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define variable using `our`.

```
package Class;

our $CONSTANT = 'foo';

# ...
# class methodes
# ...

package main;

print $Class::CONSTANT ."\n";
```

Keyword `package` works as syntactic block, so variable defined using `my` is not accessible outside this syntax block. You also have to place sigil `$` in right place. And of course it is variable, not constant.

Comment: It works too. I'll stick with use constant as Sweetie Belle and PP suggested.